# Update com calculo

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma tabela de produto e quero calcular a margem de lucro com base na nas colunas `preco_venda` e `preco_custo` fiz conforme abaixo:

```
update produto set margem_lucro=((((preco_unit/preco_custo)*100)-100))
```

Acontece o erro

> ERROR:  division by zero
>
> ERROR: division by zero SQL state: 22012

O que esta errado?

Comment: Em alguma linha o valor de preco_custo deve estar zero , não se pode dividir por zero , faça               update produto set margem_lucro= (case when preco_produto > 0 then ((((preco_unit/preco_custo)*100)-100)) else null end)

Comment: update produto set margem_lucro= (case when preco_custo > 0 then ((((preco_unit/preco_custo)*100)-100)) else null end)  isso mesmo, fiz conforme falou e deu certo, valeu Motta!

Comment: @Motta, posta como resposta

Comment: update produto set margem_lucro= (case when preco_custo > 0 then ((((preco_unit/preco_custo)*100)-100)) else null end) isso mesmo, fiz conforme falou e deu certo, valeu @Motta!

Comment: update produto set margem_lucro= (case when preco_custo > 0 then ((((preco_unit/preco_custo)*100)-100)) else null end) isso mesmo, fiz conforme falou e deu certo, valeu @Motta

Answer (score 1):

Em alguma linha o valor de preco_custo deve estar zero , não se pode dividir por zero , faça :

```
update produto set margem_lucro =
                   (case when preco_produto > 0 then 
                              ((((preco_unit/preco_custo) * 100) - 100))         
                         else null end)
```